# SQLAlchemy secondary table with multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make something like a social network using Flask and SQLAlchemy.

I made a Person model

```py
class Person(SqlAlchemyBase, UserMixin, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = Cl(sql.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    # some fields
    friends = orm.relation('Person', secondary='friendships')
```

and a Friendship model

```py
class Friendship(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'friendships'
    id = Cl(sql.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    person1_id = Cl(sql.Integer, sql.ForeignKey('persons.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    person2_id = Cl(sql.Integer, sql.ForeignKey('persons.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

it raises this exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Person.friends - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables via secondary table 'friendships'.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference from the secondary table to each of the parent and child tables.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved the problem. Everything I should do was adding primaryjoin and secondaryjoin:

```py
class Person(SqlAlchemyBase, UserMixin, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = Cl(sql.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    # some fields
    friends = orm.relation('Person', secondary='friendships', secondaryjoin=Friendship.person1_id==id, primaryjoin=Friendshup.person2_id==id)
```

This actually works!